# Accessing network share and SQL Server over the internet?

Tags: sql-server, network-share

Currently we have an old application that was written with VB 6.  The application accesses SQL server and network share over a local network.

The management wants to make it work over the internet (i.e. someone can install the application locally on their own computer, but still somehow connects to a database/network share that we host.  Of course, they want minimal change to the current application.

Exactly what you can do there?  I know you can access SQL server over the internet, but is it secure if you use SSL encryption?  Also what would be the easiest solution to access a network share?

Thanks

Comment: You want to look at using a VPN connection in order to do it securely. You will need to use software and/or hardware on both the server and client sides to do that.

Comment: (This is unlikely to work with an ancient VB6 app that has lots of inline SQL statements, but of course the ideal way to do this would be with web services.)